# Where did Fidelis go off to?

Tags: battletech

The Fidelis were released from service by Jonah Levin 21 years after the Fortress Republic came into effect.

Is there any more publications where this (secret Clan Smoke Jaguar) group is mentioned after being released? Is anything more known about them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. Nothing more has been published about them yet. Well, I take that back. A tiny bit was written in the *Era Report: 3145* and *Field Manual: 3145* books, but they don't really expand on what's in the novel much at all.

Not only that, but TPTB at Catalyst Game Labs have said that the epilogue to *Surrender Your Dreams* is no longer necessarily considered canon.

> **Surrender your Dreams:**
>
> [18:02]  I appreciate that the post-Dark Age setup is not open for discussion, but there was one thing I wanted to clarify; are the events of the epilogue in Surrender Your Dreams still considered canon, or is that glimpse of things post-3145 no longer valid?
>
> [18:04] <@Habeas2> Nerroth - We are not necessarily considering the epilogue for Surrender Your Dreams valid. It would be too restrictive to upcoming plans.

[source](http://bg.battletech.com/forums/index.php/topic,28855.msg664098.html#msg664098)

Comment: So they arent Clan Smoke Jaguar or they arent released from service or Fidelis never existed? Writers and politicians should be publicly shot by a firing squad of fans (or party peons that get f*cked over and out) in case of politicians) for being vague and giving NON-answers!

Comment: Just the events of the epilogue are iffy. So that's the release from Republic service and the decision to head for Terra to let everyone know the Smoke Jags are back in town. They are still Smoke Jaguar descendants.